# Custom navigation fails upon opening an individual record in Microsoft Access project

Tags: ms-access, navigation, vba, ms-access-forms

I'm having issues with my Microsoft Access project.

The project comprises of two forms called, `InfoForm` and `SearchBox`.

**InfoForm form**

The `InfoForm` form is the primary-form, and has the following:

- Custom navigation buttons, which are; `Next` and `Prev`
- A custom `Search button`, which opens up the `SearchBox` form.

**SearchBox form**

The `SearchBox` form is used to browse and open individual records, and has the following:

- List of available `individual records`
- `Open` button

**Individual records**

The individual records open into the `InfoForm` form.

I use this code on the `Open' button of the`SearchBox` form, as follows:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim strLN As String
strLN = Me.SearchResults.Column(0)

Dim strGN As String
strGN = Me.SearchResults.Column(1)

Dim strMN As String
strMN = Me.SearchResults.Column(2)

DoCmd.OpenForm "InfoForm", acNormal, , _
              "[Last Name] = '" & strLN & "' And " & _
              "[Given Name] = '" & strGN & "' And " & _
              "[Middle Name] = '" & strMN & "'"

DoCmd.Close acForm, "SearchBox"

End Sub
```

This code works perfectly when the `InfoForm` form is first opened, right up until an `individual record` is opened.

At this point, the navigation buttons "Next" and "Prev" on the 'InfoForm' form stop working.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Change your tags please. Add VB to it so that more people can actually see  your post and answer it.

Comment: I don't understand. I you open the form with **one** specific record, what do you expect the "Next" and "Prev" buttons to do? If the form is filtered for one record, then there is nothing to navigate to.

Comment: my database contains around 50 records. the search box was intended to got to specific records so i dont have to click "next" numerous times. Now what I'm trying to do is that, after opening one record using the search box, i want the the "Next" and "Prev" buttons to still bring me to the succeeding or preceding records in the database. Is it possible?

Comment: correction.. that is 500 records.. my database contains arouond 500 records..

Comment: Please add screenshots and addtional code to best enable the StackOverflow community to help resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

As @Andre noted, if the form is filtered to a single record then there are no succeeding or previous records to navigate to. Does your filter criteria result in a single record dataset?

An alternative is to open the form unfiltered (or with a filter that returns a restricted dataset but will usually still have multiple records) and 'go to' the desired record, then there will be succeeding and preceding records to navigate. Example from my code:

To open form:
`DoCmd.OpenForm "Samples", , , , , acDialog, strLabNum`

Then code behind the opened form:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "LabNum='" & Me.OpenArgs & "'"
Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
End Sub
```